# how to propely assemble csv file to avoid column shift

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

in my node app, I'm trying to clean up a csv file.
first, I split it into separate lines
then I replace unwanted characters in the first line (the column headers)
then I re-assemble the file by pushing individual lines into a new array, and writing that array to a new .csv file
For some reason, all my rows ending up being shifted by 1 position with respect to the header row.
I have opened the resulting file in a vu editor, and can see, that all rows somehow acquired a "," character at the besieging

I know I'm doing something incorrectly, but can not see what that is.

Here is my code:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');

var fs = require('fs');

var csv = require("fast-csv");

var workbook = XLSX.readFile('Lineitems.xls');

var worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];

var csv_conversion = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);

var csv_lines = csv_conversion.split('\n');

var dirtyHeaderLine = csv_lines[0];

var cleanHeaderLine = dirtyHeaderLine.replace(/\./g,"")
    .replace(/"'"/g,"")
    .replace(/","/g,"")
    .replace(/"\/"/g,"")
    .replace(/"#"/g,"");

cleanHeaderLine = cleanHeaderLine.replace(/,+$/, "");

console.log(cleanHeaderLine);

csv_lines[0] = cleanHeaderLine;

var newCsvLines = [];

csv_lines.forEach(function(line){
    newCsvLines.push(line + "\n");
});

fs.writeFile('clean_file.csv', newCsvLines, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('clean file saved');
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't letting `fast-csv` write the CSV (scroll down to writing https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv)? I'm guessing your commas are coming because you are trying to write an array into a file, and the extra commas are the array separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any glaring errors here (maybe something with your regex? Not an expert on those) but this will solve your issue.

```
if (line.charAt(0) == ',') { line = line.substring(1); }
```

Adjust your variables accordingly. I don't think I have the same case as you.

EDIT: Here's a JSBin of it working.

http://jsbin.com/mirocedagi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Just tried it - same result. drives me crazy. When I look at individual lines - all is fine, no commas at the beginning of each line. as soon as the actual file is written - all lines but the header somehow get a comma at the beginning...

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood. I thought it was all the lines, not the header, with the comma. Let me adjust.

Comment: the header is actually fine. it is all the other lines that somehow get a comma at their beginning

Comment: I may have solved a part of it by switching around "\n" and line:  newCsvLines.push("\n" + line);  Now all rows are aligned with the header, but I do now have an empty line at the very top of the file. will try to work on that now...

Comment: I see a list in the bin. where do I go to see your example in there?

Comment: Try this link. It shows just the console and the JS: http://jsbin.com/mirocedagi/1/edit?js,console